# SQL grouping and sum claims totals

Tags: mysql

I am trying to group the following:

```
CLAIM #    LINE SEQ   AMNT BILLED   AMOUNT ALLOWED   AMOUNT PAID   COPAY
LA123456          1            20               18            15       3
LA123456          2            10                5             5       0
LA123456          3            50               30            30       0
MS123456          1            20               18            15       3
MS123456          2            10                5             5       0
MS123456          3            50               30            30       0
```

I am expecting to see something like this:

```
CLAIM #     AMOUNT BILLED   AMOUNT ALLOWED   AMOUNT PAID   COPAY
LA123456               80               53            50       3
MS123456               80               53            50       3
```

Any advice on how to do it?

Comment: This is a very basic `group by` statement, just search for the first 4 words in your title and you'll find lots of examples...  What have you tried and where are you having problems?

Answer (score 0):

```
//The syntax is select sum(field1),sum(field2)from table_name group by field3

select sum(AMNT BILLED),sum(AMOUNT ALLOWED),sum(AMOUNT PAID),sum(COPAY) from table_name group by CLAIM
```

This is very basic

See the following for reference

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sum-function.htm

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/